# How can I combine two Django views into one?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am tring to combine two Django views into one. The goal is to be able to render a Django form and a folium map on the same page. Below is my best attempt at combining the views into a Combined view. Please let me know where I went wrong.

```
import folium
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View
from django.views.generic import FormView
from .models import StLouisCityLandTax
from .forms import StLouisCityLandTaxForm


class formView(FormView):
    form = StLouisCityLandTaxForm
    template_name = 'maps/partials/_form.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = StLouisCityLandTaxForm()
        return render(request, 'maps/partials/_form.html', {"form": form})


def folium_map(request):
    properties = StLouisCityLandTax.objects.all()

    # create a Folium map centered on St Louis
    m = folium.Map(location=[38.627003, -90.199402], zoom_start=11)

    # add markers to the map for each station
    for i in properties:
        coordinates = (i.point_y, i.point_x)
        folium.Marker(coordinates).add_to(m)

    context = {'map': m._repr_html_()}
    return render(request, 'maps/partials/_map.html', context)

class CombinedView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        context = {
            'form': form,
            'map': m._repr_html_(),
        }
        return render(request, 'maps/StLouisCityLandTaxSale.html', context)
```

I tried the code listed above.

Comment: Could you specify what is the problem exactly? What you want to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should create a new file and name it `utils.py` then make 2 functions that do main things of your views like this:

**utils.py**

```
import folium
from .models import StLouisCityLandTax
from .forms import StLouisCityLandTaxForm

def formViewFunction():
    form = StLouisCityLandTaxForm()
    
    return form

def mapFunction():
    properties = StLouisCityLandTax.objects.all()

    # create a Folium map centered on St Louis
    m = folium.Map(location=[38.627003, -90.199402], zoom_start=11)

    # add markers to the map for each station
    for i in properties:
        coordinates = (i.point_y, i.point_x)
        folium.Marker(coordinates).add_to(m)
        
    return m
```

After `utils.py` you need to complete your views:

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View
from .utils import *


def formViewPage(request):
    form = formViewFunction()
    
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    
    return render(request, 'template_name.html', context)


def allObjectsMap(request):
    m = mapFunction()
    
    context = {
        'map': m,
    }
    
    return render(request, 'template_name2.html', context)


def both(request):
    form = formViewFunction()
    
    m = mapFunction()
    
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'map': m,
    }
    
    return render(request, 'template_name3.html', context)
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! This worked perfectly! I had never heard of a utils.py file. I've been stuck for a week. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: I'm happy to solve your problem, good luck.